# How to not include in regex a literal after including it in the first group?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, capturing-group

I am using preg_match_all() to match some strings.

this is my code

```
preg_match_all('@([a-zA-Z0-9,\(\)\-\s\.\#:]*)Date From: [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}([, \s]*[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})*\s(Division Type: [A-Z ]*)*@m', $string, $match);
```

this is the output

https://regex101.com/r/hE3iO2/1

Now, I want to add a `/` to the first group to include the literal `/` in the capturing group and this happen

from this

```
([a-zA-Z0-9,\(\)\-\s\.\#:]*)
```

to this

```
([a-zA-Z0-9,\(\)\-\s\.\#:/]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/wM1rW7/1

How can I prevent this to happen when adding `/` to the group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your regex non-greedy:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9,()\s.#:/-]*?)Date From: [0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}([, \s]*[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})*\s(Division Type: [A-Z ]*)*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wM1rW7/2)